# Unable to get custom metadata from S3 Bucket with Amplify ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, metadata

In my ReactJS amplify website I would like to get my S3 bucket items and get the metadata. I tried the following code, and get a **blank** metadata as a result:

```
   s3.listObjects(params, function(err,data){
      if(err){
        console.log("There was an error getting bucket contents:", err);
      }
      else{
      var bucketContents = data.Contents;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(bucketContents));
      this.setState(state => {
        return { s3Data: bucketContents };
      });

      // get meta data
      for (var i = 0; i < bucketContents.length; i++) {
        var urlParams = { Bucket: bucketName, Key: bucketContents[i].Key };
        imageTitles.push(bucketContents[i].Key);
        s3.headObject(
          {
              Bucket : bucketName,
              Key: bucketContents[i].Key
          },
          function(err,data){
            if(err){
              console.log(err.message);
            }
            else{
              console.log("HEAD RESULTS:");
              console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
          });
```

I have a s3 bucket with 2 custom tags. Inside the s3 bucket I have added the following CORS policy for those tags:

[image]

Using amplify cli I have ran amplify pull to update. However I don't see it in my CORS policy locally on my code. 
[image]

So trying to be useful, I tried *manually* adding it in the file. Still doesn't work.

Why is this happening, and how can I populate the metadata?

Comment: maybe this can help https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2903

Answer (score 0):

I can retrieve the metadata after enabling CORS headers as explained here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/232

```
export const get = (filename, level) => {
  /*First enable CORS headers for the metadata you want to retrieve. Manual setup: 
    S3 console > select bucket > Click on Permissions > CORS Configuration > Add x-amz-meta-* keys:
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-audience</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-location</ExposeHeader>
  */
  Storage.get(filename, {
    level,
    download: true 
  })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```